# Tips for responsive website making

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in web development but I'm very interested in this field, regarding making responsive websites.

Is it good programming practice when you hide an html element(for desktop viewport) and display another html element when on a smaller screen size even though both elements have the same content, for example a contact form? I did hide the "html element" because I found it difficult using media queries...

Note: the question is not really about the content of the html element that I'm trying to hide or show. I just want to know if it is good practice in programming to doing such? Thank you

Comment: Which "HTML element" did you hide? You should provide some code showing what you have done so far and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have to send the markup twice, which uses more bandwidth, and when the CSS doesn't get applied (e.g. if it is being read by a search engine indexing bot or by someone using Lynx) then the content is duplicated.

Generally people want to do this because they want to reorder the content. Look at using Flexbox (including the `order` property) to do that instead.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers and explanation...i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Answer is not, it is not good practice. You need to try to avoid duplicating the same logical elements for desktop and mobile. Try to use one element and adjust it with media queries.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers and explanation...i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best way to approach responsive design is to avoid hiding and showing content as much as possible. Often it's best to design your site to accommodate resizing or reordering elements as opposed to simply removing them on certain screens (particularly where you seem to be asking if you should show an element with the same content?)

Obviously the exception here would be dropdown navigation menus.

This is why people tend to say you should design mobile first. That way only the most important elements are present, and you're not simply hiding elements unnecessarily.

I hope that makes sense. You already seem to understand media queries so I advise you practise with altering elements as opposed to hiding and showing them. That method is not so great for accessibility and readability of your code.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers and explanation...i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good practice. Your html is being bloated with no extra importance of the codes.

It also get more difficulty traversing your html tree structure. So after all it's not a good practice. Just try to use tricks and hacks to achieve the same result like you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers and explanation...i really appreciate it